# Low Level Web based Editor

Tags: javascript, html, editor

Is there any open source low level web based editor ?
(I'm aware of wysiwyg editors like CKEditor, I'm  looking for something different. )

- The editor should work in a way like [new Google Docs editor](https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/05/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html).
- The editor should take user's input key by key and should build the text. so that the client JavaScript can have complete control while editing.
- Why i need it ? I need to build a DSL editor for my application with syntax highlighting and auto complete.
- I already found code editor ace http://ace.ajax.org . but it has lots of features that I don't need, so I'm searching for alternatives.
- I'm looking for similar lightweight editor, so that I can add my features (like autocomplete ) easily to it.

Comment: Really sounds like ace is what you already want

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen Aloha Editor?

HTML5 and fast too:

http://www.aloha-editor.org/

It's open source there are no iframes and you can access the page contents just as they are.

It's the future of html editors.

Answer (score 0):

There's collabedit:

http://collabedit.com/